# Showing tables from specific database with Pyspark and Hive

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, beeline

Having some databases and tables in them in Hive instance. I'd like to show tables for some specific database (let's say 3_db).

```
+------------------+--+
|  database_name   |
+------------------+--+
| 1_db             |
| 2_db             |
| 3_db             |
+------------------+--+
```

If I enter beeline from bash-nothing complex there, I just do the following:

```
show databases;
show tables from 3_db;
```

When I'm using pyspark via ipython notebeook- my cheap tricks are not working there and give me error on the second line (show tables from 3_db) instead:

```
sqlContext.sql('show databases').show()
sqlContext.sql('show tables from 3_db').show()
```

What seems to be wrong and why's the same code works in one place and don't work in another?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
sqlContext.sql("show tables in 3_db").show()
```

Comment: db_tbl_list = sql("show tables in my_hive_db like '*ai*' ")

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility is to use the [Catalog](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Catalog) methods:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.catalog.listTables("3_db")
```

Just be aware that in PySpark this method returns a `list` and in Scala, it returns a `DataFrame`.

Comment: SparkSession is the more "modern" way, rather than sqlContext. Pls upvote.

Answer (score 7):

There are two possible ways to achieve this, but they differ a lot in terms of efficiency.

---

**Using SQL**

This is the most efficient approach:

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark_session.sql("show tables in db_name").show()
```

**Using `catalog.listTables()`**

The following is more inefficient compared to the previous approach, as it also loads tables' metadata:

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark_session.catalog.listTables("db_name")
```